# Aligning button to the right of text in navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Here is my code so far for the header, you will see that the text explaining whose account it is, and the button to logout do not alight up with the button to the right of the text.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>DroneReg - File Section 333 Easy</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Source+Sans+Pro|Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

    <!--Start Meta Content-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">DroneReg</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
            <!--start difficulty-->
                    <p class="navbar-text navbar-right">Signed in as, <a href="#" class="navbar-link" style="color: white;">Mark Otto</a></p>
                <div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn pull-right"><a href="/logout">Logout</a></button>
                </div>                      
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the code you want to the right with:

```
<div class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
```

Like this:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
    <div class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
        <p class="navbar-text navbar-right">Signed in as, <a href="#" class="navbar-link" style="color: white;">Mark Otto</a></p>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn pull-right"><a href="/logout">Logout</a></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove navbar-right and pull-right from your current setup (see [Component Alignment](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-component-alignment) in the Docs for more info), then wrap `<div class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>` around your links.

If you want these to keep the alignment of the default navbar links on viewports under 768px, you'll need to add your own CSS as navbar-link is general used for links outside of the default navigation component. **Keep in mind if that you may want/need to add a new class to these if you don't want to change them globally.

> For folks using standard links that are not within the regular navbar
>   navigation component, use the .navbar-link class to add the proper
>   colors for the default and inverse navbar options.

*Sidenote: Your also missing the `navbar-header` class which will make a significant difference in the structure. See [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

See working example Snippet at FullPage.

```css
.navbar-nav .logout-btn a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #777;
}
.navbar-nav a.navbar-link {
  color: white;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-nav .logout-btn,
  .navbar-nav .navbar-text {
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">DroneReg</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

      <div class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
        <p class="navbar-text">Signed in as, <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Mark Otto</a>
        </p>
        <li>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn logout-btn"><a href="/logout">Logout</a>
          </button>
        </li>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```